# Dynamic text inside button during a browser zoom

Tags: html, css, asp.net

On Firefox browser (version 35.0.1), my button looks like so:

[image]

However, after zooming out in the browser, some of the text starts to get cut off:

[image]

I tried seeing if `text-overflow` or `text-rendering` had something that could help. However, I do not want to use ellipsis and messing with the rendering CSS didn't seem to work. I want the text to dynamically changed in size as a zoom out (or a zoom in) happens. Is there a way to do this?

HTML:

```
<td>
    <button id="ctl00_phBody_btnReplaceDrive" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%; text-align: left;" onclick="return ChooseDiskToReplace();">
        <i class="icon-exchange" style="padding-right: 7px"></i>
        Replace existing hard drive
    </button>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-primary {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #565656;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: try changing button element with div element, happened with me once, div was my solution

Comment: Cannot replicate.- http://jsfiddle.net/27xx769q/

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate that behaviour with the zoom of my browser, but I think that using relative units one the font-size property should solve it.

Try it using em instead of px, for example "font-size: 0.875em;"

EDIT: I just managed to replicate it in jsfiddle, and em units solved it.
http://jsfiddle.net/dmt6qwxb/

```
    .btn-primary {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #565656;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    max-width: 190px; //I couldn't replicate it without this
}
.btn {

    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
```